# Como converter campo texto com máscara para double

Tags: php, html, string, conversão-de-tipo, double

Tenho um campo no `html` do tipo texto que possui uma máscara de moeda. 
Tenho que salvar este valor em um campo do tipo `double` no banco de dados, porém estou com problema na conversão, onde o valor que seria posterior à vírgula é suprimido após a conversão.

**código HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label " for="adiantamento">
            Adiantamento
    </label>
    <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                R$
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="adiantamento" name="adiantamento" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Código PHP** (Substituo a vírgula pelo ponto e tento fazer a conversão para double)

```
 $adiantamento=str_replace(',','.',$_POST['adiantamento']);
 $adiantamento_C=(double)$adiantamento;
```

**Tela Formulário**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tela impressão string e double**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que tá acontecendo é que o ponto de separação de milhar está sendo interpretado como separador decimal, é só tirar ele antes de substituir a vírgula:

```
$adiantamento = str_replace('.', '', $_POST['adiantamento']);
$adiantamento = str_replace(',', '.', $adiantamento);
$adiantamento_C = (double)$adiantamento;
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema acontece quando você tem um valor alto onde aparecem a "," e o "." como por exemplo: 5.150,50

Você está apenas substituindo as virgulas por ponto, ou seja, após o seu replace o valor fica dessa forma 5.150.50
Valores do tipo double tem que ter apenas um ponto, então antes de você substituir as virgulas por ponto você deve remover os pontos.

```
$adiantamento = str_replace( '.' , '', $_POST['adiantamento'] ); // Removeu todos os pontos
$adiantamento = str_replace( ',', '.', $adiantamento); // Substitui todas as virgulas por ponto.
```

Se quiser economizar 1 linha de código você também pode fazer assim:

```
$adiantamento = str_replace( ',', '.', str_replace( '.' , '', $_POST['adiantamento'] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa seria utilizar um único `str_replace`, *não há necessidade de utilizar isto duas vezes*.

```
echo str_replace(['.', ','], ['', '.'], $valor);
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e62780405f980f7c51f7f248d0938a568421fc88)

---

Você também pode utilizar o `strtr`:

```
echo strtr($valor, ['.' => '', ',' => '.']);
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d849b15ee86b14ccb17337279d748dc647053462)

A ideia é a mesma das respostas anteriores, remover o `.` e depois converter o `,` para `.`.

---

Vale lembrar que caso a entrada esteja mal formatada, as funções acima não vão resolver, considerando:

```
 $valor = '1,234,56';
```

Isso irá converter para:

```
 1.234.56
```

Que no final resultará em:

```
 1.234
```

---

Para prevenir que isso ocorra é preciso validar o número de `.` que existem ou verificar se o valor em `double` é igual.

Por exemplo:

```
$valor = '1,234,56'; // Inválido

$valor = strtr($valor, ['.' => '', ',' => '.']); // = 1.234.56

if(strcmp((double)$valor, $valor) !== 0){
    echo 'Erro'; // = Cairá aqui.
}
```

[Isso irá ocorrer](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/713d74df262d6e0c5d3a152ccc1aa9004bf3ac83) porque `1.234.56` é diferente de `1.234`, seu valor como double.

Uma coisa que pode fazer também é validar o valor de entrada de inicio, ao menos verificando se existe uma virgula, caso isso seja obrigatório.